# Concact Multiple SQL Rows where Preceding Columns are the Same with Table Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT stock_items.stockcode, 
   x_apvma_product.pcode, 
   x_apvma_product.fpname, 
   x_apvma_product.sname, 
   x_apvma_host.hostdesc, 
   x_apvma_pest.pestdesc
FROM   x_apvma_product 
   INNER JOIN stock_items 
           ON stock_items.x_apvma_product_no = x_apvma_product.pcode 
   INNER JOIN x_apvma_product_use 
           ON x_apvma_product_use.pcode = x_apvma_product.pcode 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN x_apvma_host 
                ON x_apvma_host.hostcode = x_apvma_product_use.hostcode 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN x_apvma_pest 
                ON x_apvma_pest.pestcode = x_apvma_product_use.pestcode
WHERE  x_apvma_product.pcode IN (SELECT x_apvma_product_no 
                             FROM   stock_items) 
   AND stock_items.web_show = 'Y';
```

Which results in this (have chosen results from one stock item as there are over 74k rows to entire query):

```
stockcode   pcode   fpname                          sname                       hostdesc                        pestdesc
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   POTTING MIX, COMPOST, MANURE    FUNGUS GNAT
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   POTTING MIX, COMPOST, MANURE    SHORE FLY
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   AZALEA                          AZALEA LACE BUG
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   MARIGOLD                        YELLOW LEAFHOPPER
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   MARIGOLD                        LEAFHOPPER
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORCHID                          CITRUS MEALY BUG
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                CITRUS MEALY BUG
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   PALM                            CITRUS MEALY BUG
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   GERBERA GREENHOUSE              WHITEFLY
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                GREENHOUSE WHITEFLY
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   FUCHSIA GREENHOUSE              WHITEFLY
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   GERBERA SILVERLEAF              WHITEFLY
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                SILVERLEAF WHITEFLY
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   FUCHSIA SILVERLEAF              WHITEFLY
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                SCALE INSECTS
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ROSE                            ROSE APHID
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                PLAGUE THRIPS
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   MARIGOLD                        VEGETABLE LEAFHOPPER
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   LILLY PILLY                     PSYLLID OR LERP INSECT
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                GREEN COFFEE SCALE
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                PULVINARIA SCALE
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   AZALEA                          GREENHOUSE THRIP
9075    58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   ORNAMENTAL PLANT                NIGRA SCALE
```

How do I change the query so I get 1 row for multiple `x_apvma_host.hostdesc` **and have the multiple results of `x_apvma_pest.pestdesc` concatenated into one, separated by commas**? This needs to be per stockcode of course.

Result should be:

```
Stockcode   Pcode   Fpname                              Sname                       Hostdesc                        pestconcat
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Azalea                          Azalea Lace Bug, Greenhouse Thrip
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Fuchsia                         Greenhouse Whitefly, Silverleaf Whitefly
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Gerbera                         Greenhouse Whitefly, Silverleaf Whitefly
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Lilly Pilly                     Psyllid Or Lerp Insect
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Marigold                        Leafhopper, Vegetable Leafhopper, Yellow Leafhopper
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Orchid                          Citrus Mealy Bug
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Ornamental Plant                Citrus Mealy Bug, Green Coffee Scale, Greenhouse Whitefly, Nigra Scale, Plague Thrips, Pulvinaria Scale, Scale Insects, Silverleaf Whitefly
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Palm                            Citrus Mealy Bug
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Potting Mix, Compost, Manure    Fungus Gnat, Shore Fly
9075        58558   CROWN 225SL SYSTEMIC INSECTICIDE    EVERRIS AUSTRALIA PTY LTD   Rose                            Rose Aphid
```

I'm aware that you can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` functions, however all the tutorials I have found are much simpler and don't involve joined tables, so far I haven't been able to work out how to use these in my situation and get the correct result.

Some test data here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3f4e3/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add [SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data.

You can try the following:

**Edit**: Query updated after sql fiddle added.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT stock_items.stockcode,
           x_apvma_product.pcode,
           x_apvma_product.fpname,
           x_apvma_product.sname,
           x_apvma_host.hostdesc,
           x_apvma_pest.pestdesc
    FROM   x_apvma_product
           INNER JOIN stock_items
                   ON stock_items.x_apvma_product_no = x_apvma_product.pcode
           INNER JOIN x_apvma_product_use
                   ON x_apvma_product_use.pcode = x_apvma_product.pcode
           LEFT OUTER JOIN x_apvma_host
                        ON x_apvma_host.hostcode = x_apvma_product_use.hostcode
           LEFT OUTER JOIN x_apvma_pest
                        ON x_apvma_pest.pestcode = x_apvma_product_use.pestcode
    WHERE stock_items.web_show = 'Y'
) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
        stockcode,
        pcode,
        fpname,
        sname,
        hostdesc,
        pestdesc = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+pestdesc  
                          FROM CTE c 
                          WHERE c.hostdesc = c2.hostdesc 
                          FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM CTE c2
```

Also there is no need of condition `x_apvma_product.pcode IN (SELECT x_apvma_product_no FROM stock_items)` because you already had `JOIN` between those tables.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5d290/1)

Comment: Thanks @MAK - I think we are close on this one, I get a error when running that `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 'x_apvma_product_use.pestcode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` however if I add that to the group by clause, the result i get is the same as my first query in my question...? Sorry, the answer may be obvious, however I'm still learning!

Comment: Changing to `DISTINCT` still resolves the same results as my initial query. Also is a comma needed after `FOR XML PATH(''))`

Comment: @DaleP, Please add SQL Fiddle link with some sample data.

Comment: @DaleP, I have added SQL Fiddle link please check in my answer.

Comment: thats not working... I have finally setup some real data in SQLFiddle - sorry for the delay - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3f4e3/1/0 - and yes it does need the `x_apvma_product.pcode IN (SELECT x_apvma_product_no  FROM   stock_items) ` as it is drawing from a massive table with a lot of data not relevant to our stock items.... so that `where` clause drastically cuts down on the number of returned results to only relevant ones.

Comment: Addition to previous comment - Sorry you are very correct! that `WHERE` clause is not needed as you say (sorry I added in the stock_items table later, and didn't think to remove the `WHERE` clause)

Comment: Thanks very much  @MAK - that works :) My only problem now is the query takes forever to run on the real database (without specifying a specific stockcode), but that's not your problem!

Comment: @DaleP, Tip: You just need proper indexing on these columns `stock_items.x_apvma_product_no, x_apvma_product.pcode, x_apvma_product_use.pcode , x_apvma_host.hostcode, x_apvma_product_use.hostcode, x_apvma_pest.pestcode, x_apvma_product_use.pestcode`, Nice time there :)

Comment: That did it! I already had nonclustered index on those and clustered on the `SEQNO` column. The query in fact was taking over 10mins so i cancelled it... Have now deleted index on `SEQNO` and created clustered index on `pcode` etc (especially `x_apvma_product_use` table which is massive) - whole query now takes 11 seconds with 4k results (down from 74k results when the last column results were not combined as they are now with your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can Change your `LEFT OUTER JOIN x_apvma_host`

to `LEFT OUTER JOIN (select x,y from x_apvma_host group by x,y) x_apvma_host`

reference:

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which runs even faster is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stock_items.stockcode [sku],
           x_apvma_product.pcode,
           x_apvma_product.fpname,
           x_apvma_product.sname,
           x_apvma_host.hostdesc,
           x_apvma_pest.pestdesc
           into #TEMP_APVMA_Table
    FROM   x_apvma_product
           INNER JOIN stock_items
                   ON stock_items.x_apvma_product_no = x_apvma_product.pcode
           INNER JOIN x_apvma_product_use
                   ON x_apvma_product_use.pcode = x_apvma_product.pcode
           LEFT OUTER JOIN x_apvma_host
                        ON x_apvma_host.hostcode = x_apvma_product_use.hostcode
           LEFT OUTER JOIN x_apvma_pest
                        ON x_apvma_pest.pestcode = x_apvma_product_use.pestcode
    WHERE stock_items.web_show = 'Y'
 ;
SELECT DISTINCT 
        sku,
        hostdesc,
        pestdesc = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+pestdesc  
                          FROM #TEMP_APVMA_Table c 
                          WHERE c.hostdesc = c2.hostdesc 
                          AND c.sku = c2.sku
                          FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM #TEMP_APVMA_Table c2
```